# Weird redirection problem

Tags: nodes, redirection

I've got this website I'm maintaining and one thing about it is driving me mad. Anonymous users have the permission to create nodes of this content type, and when they do, they are redirected to the front page so fast that they can't see the messages after (there is supposed to be messages). This happens only with anonymous users and only with that content type. Below are the steps I've taken to debug this.

- Put a `dpm(debug_backtrace())` as the first line of `drupal_goto()` (no usable output)
  *I changed theme, but I didn't try with the Bartik theme
- I've changed the machine name of the content type

#### Some more facts

- There are only 2 custom modules, and they are both disabled
- I disabled all the rules I was using
- I do NOT have the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module installed, nor Global Redirect
- I have disabled all the rules and no PHP in blocks/fields (as far as I know)

How do I further debug this?

Comment: When I  run out of ideas, I start disabling all modules until the problem is resolved

Comment: There's something not quite right here - if there's a server side redirect happening, then messages will _not_ be rendered on the 'middle' page - they will be kept in session storage until the next page is actually physically rendered, so the home page in this case. If you're not seeing that message on the homepage, it might suggest there's something more than an errant redirect happening

Comment: Another possible cause can be this module: r4032login

Comment: Clive suggest that there could be some js redirect. Could this be the case?

Comment: use no script firefox/chrome addon, to test if there is some js redirect.

Comment: @NoSssweat nothing :S

Comment: backup your site, then change to the default drupal theme. Perhaps there is something somewhere in a template file. This is the fastest way to check if there is a template file that's causing this.

Comment: check your content type, you might have some php or js redirect in it

Comment: I read you disabled all rules, but what about rules components? `admin/config/workflow/rules/components`

Comment: @NoSssweat there is one component, and it's for determining whether you are an administrator.